# Real-time show/hide script with admin for current visitors

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-plugins

I run a lot of online classes and I've been looking all over the place and I'm not sure it cna even be done... but essentially I send a few hundred people to watch a special video on my site at a set time ie:7:00PM and I'd like to be able to from, behind the scenes, hit a button show a thank you/offer button under the presentation.

Is there anything out there that does this? Can html5 or jQuery do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to manually do that, but if you are looking to push a button to have text appear on all instances of a browser that runs your video, you need to use a websocket, although IE has issues with HTML5 websockets still.

You can use Flash to circumvent any issues with websockets, as flash has been able to do this for awhile now.  You can look at Pusher - which is cross browser compatible and will let you essentially "push" data to your users with the use of a pusher event

For more information on pusher - check out http://www.pusher.com - they are free for a limited amount of connections - after which, you have to start paying

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can accomplish this with [WebSockets](http://www.websocket.org/).  You will also have to choose a server in which to implement a WebSockets server, such as Socket.io etc...

Comment: websocket needs a server process (php or something else) to run constanly, so difficult to implement if it is a share host